# Android Studio - Reformat code "Optimize imports" order not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import

When i'm organizing my imports in Android studio (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>). I don't understand how Android Studio define the order.

What I notice is that, imports start with common name like `android.*`, `java.*`, `com.*`, which are grouped alone, separated with a blank line, then all other imports are grouped bellow alphabetically.

In my project, shared with other people, `androidx.*` classes are also grouped alone, right after `android.*` classes. But in my case, these libraries aren't sorted alone but put at the end, mixed with all other imports.

Ex:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.inject.Inject;

// import other classes
```

Becomes for me after Reformat code :

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.C;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.inject.Inject;

// import other classes + ANDROIDX CLASSES
```

This is problem, as every time me or a colleague works on a class and use the auto reformat option, git consider it legitimately as change. And sometimes, conflict occurs.

Any idea  on how to fix this import order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

The import layout can be modified in `settings > Editor > Code Style > Java`. Then in the *Imports* tab, at the bottom there's a section for the import Layout !

Si I added a new package bellow `android.*` and a blank line.

[image: Update import layout]